# How to resolve below query by flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to fix the div white background boxes height 100% under "Test Your Audio, Video & Network" & "Host Control Panel" as shown in the links below.
Below is the 2 images link in which that I did the HTML and what I want the actual design by flexbox.

1) This is the first image that I did.

[image: This is the first image that I did.]

2) This is what I want.

[image]

Comment: show us your code!!!!!

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] to see what makes for a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DCR here is the link, where you can check the code
"https://jsfiddle.net/3v9k4tpa/1/"